# Не отслеживается первое нажатие кнопки, после запуска программы

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Весь [код](https://github.com/Hokins87/Calculator).

После запуска программы, первое нажатие кнопки не отслеживается. Если использовать закомментированные строки и изменить `fxml` файл, все работает корректно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть затруднение?

Возможно ли создать только один экземпляр класса `MyEvent()` для всех кнопок, а не так, как у меня в коде для метода `btnClick(ActionEvent event)`?

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

}

private double oper1 = 0, oper2 = 0;
private String operation = "";

@FXML
private Button btn0, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9;

@FXML
private Button btnClear, btnPoint, btnResult, btnDivide, btnSum, btnSub, btnMultiply;

@FXML
private TextField txtField;

@FXML
private AnchorPane lblDisplay;

public void btnClick(ActionEvent event) {
    btn0.setOnAction(new MyEvent());
    btn1.setOnAction(new MyEvent());
    btn2.setOnAction(new MyEvent());
    btn3.setOnAction(new MyEvent());
    btn4.setOnAction(new MyEvent());
    btn5.setOnAction(new MyEvent());
    btn6.setOnAction(new MyEvent());
    btn7.setOnAction(new MyEvent());
    btn8.setOnAction(new MyEvent());
    btn9.setOnAction(new MyEvent());
}

/*
 * public void addNum0(ActionEvent event) { 
 * if(btn0 == event.getSource()){
 * if(txtField.getText().equals("0")){ 
 * txtField.setText(txtField.getText() +
 * ""); }else{ txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + "0");
 * System.out.println("0"); } } }
 *
 * public void addNum1(ActionEvent event) {
 * if(txtField.getText().equals("0")){ txtField.setText(""); }
 * txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + "1"); System.out.println("1"); }
 * 
 * public void addNum2(ActionEvent event) {
 * if(txtField.getText().equals("0")){ txtField.setText(""); }
 * txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + "2"); System.out.println("2"); }
 * 
 * public void addNum3(ActionEvent event) {
 * if(txtField.getText().equals("0")){ txtField.setText(""); }
 * txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + "3"); System.out.println("3"); }
 * 
 * public void addNum4(ActionEvent event) {
 * if(txtField.getText().equals("0")){ txtField.setText(""); }
 * txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + "4"); System.out.println("4"); }
 * 
 * public void addNum5(ActionEvent event) {
 * if(txtField.getText().equals("0")){ txtField.setText(""); }
 * txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + "5"); System.out.println("5"); }
 * 
 * public void addNum6(ActionEvent event) {
 * if(txtField.getText().equals("0")){ txtField.setText(""); }
 * txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + "6"); System.out.println("6"); }
 * 
 * public void addNum7(ActionEvent event) {
 * if(txtField.getText().equals("0")){ txtField.setText(""); }
 * txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + "7"); System.out.println("7"); }
 * 
 * public void addNum8(ActionEvent event) {
 * if(txtField.getText().equals("0")){ txtField.setText(""); }
 * txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + "8"); System.out.println("8"); }
 * 
 * public void addNum9(ActionEvent event) {
 * if(txtField.getText().equals("0")){ txtField.setText(""); }
 * txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + "9"); System.out.println("9"); }
 */

public void clearDisplay(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Clear");
    txtField.setText("0");
}

public void addDivide(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Divide");
    oper1 = Double.valueOf(txtField.getText());
    txtField.setText("");
    operation = "/";
}

public void addMultiply(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Multiply");
    oper1 = Double.valueOf(txtField.getText());
    txtField.setText("");
    operation = "*";
}

public void addSubtract(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Subtract");
    oper1 = Double.valueOf(txtField.getText());
    txtField.setText("");
    operation = "-";
}

public void addSum(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Sum");
    oper1 = Double.valueOf(txtField.getText());
    txtField.setText("");
    operation = "+";
}

public void addPoint(ActionEvent event) {
    if (btnPoint == event.getSource()) {
        if (!txtField.getText().contains(".")) {
            txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + ".");
            System.out.println("Point");
        }
    }
}

public void result(ActionEvent event) {
    MathCalculator math = new MathCalculator();
    oper2 = Double.valueOf(txtField.getText());
    txtField.setText("");
    if (operation.equals("/")) {
        math.divide(oper1, oper2);
    } else if (operation.equals("*")) {
        math.multiply(oper1, oper2);
    } else if (operation.equals("-")) {
        math.subtract(oper1, oper2);
    } else {
        math.sum(oper1, oper2);
    }
    txtField.setText(String.valueOf(oper1) + " " + operation + " " + String.valueOf(oper2) + " = "
            + String.valueOf(math.getResult()));
}

class MyEvent implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();
        if (txtField.getText().equals("0")) {
            txtField.setText("");
        }
        txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + btn.getText());
        switch (btn.getText()) {
        case "0":
            System.out.println("0");
            break;
        case "1":
            System.out.println("1");
            break;
        case "2":
            System.out.println("2");
            break;
        case "3":
            System.out.println("3");
            break;
        case "4":
            System.out.println("4");
            break;
        case "5":
            System.out.println("5");
            break;
        case "6":
            System.out.println("6");
            break;
        case "7":
            System.out.println("7");
            break;
        case "8":
            System.out.println("8");
            break;
        case "9":
            System.out.println("9");
            break;
        }
    }

}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane fx:id="lblDisplay" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="290.0" prefWidth="257.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.MyController">
<children>
<GridPane layoutX="27.0" layoutY="79.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="240.0">
<columnConstraints>
<ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
<ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
<ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
<ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
</columnConstraints>
<rowConstraints>
<RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
<RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
<RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
<RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
</rowConstraints>
<children>
<Button fx:id="btn8" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="108.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" text="8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
<Button fx:id="btn9" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="108.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="9" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
<Button fx:id="btn7" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="108.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="7" />
<Button fx:id="btn2" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="185.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
<Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="185.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
<Button fx:id="btn4" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="144.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
<Button fx:id="btn0" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
<Button fx:id="btnResult" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#result" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="=" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
<Button fx:id="btn3" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="185.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
<Button fx:id="btn5" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="144.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" text="5" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
<Button fx:id="btnSum" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addSum" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="+" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
<Button fx:id="btnPoint" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addPoint" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="." GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
<Button fx:id="btnDivide" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="108.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addDivide" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="/" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
<Button fx:id="btn6" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="144.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="6" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
<Button fx:id="btnMultiply" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="144.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addMultiply" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="*" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
<Button fx:id="btnSub" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="185.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addSubtract" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
</children>
</GridPane>
<Button fx:id="btnClear" layoutX="9.0" layoutY="54.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clearDisplay" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="240.0" text="Clear" />
<TextField fx:id="txtField" alignment="TOP_RIGHT" editable="false" layoutX="9.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="240.0" text="0" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Советую прочитать о том, [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: FXML приложите к коду.

Comment: Код с fxml добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Затруднение в том, что у тебя обработчик вешается на кнопки только после того, как ты кликнул на кнопку. Поэтому у тебя срабатывает не сразу, а только после второго нажатия.

В данном случае, если ты хочешь повесить свой обработчик MyEvent, тебе не надо прописывать в `fxml` обработчик на `onClick`. Чтобы был один экземпляр, создай его один раз и сразу повесь на кнопки, например, в методе `initialize()`

В твоем случае правильная `fxml` будет выглядеть так:

```
<children>
<Button fx:id="btn8" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="108.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
<Button fx:id="btn9" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="108.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="9" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
<Button fx:id="btn7" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="108.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="7" />
<Button fx:id="btn2" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="185.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
<Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="185.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
<Button fx:id="btn4" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="144.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
<Button fx:id="btn0" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
<Button fx:id="btnResult" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#result" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="=" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
<Button fx:id="btn3" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="185.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
<Button fx:id="btn5" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="144.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="5" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
<Button fx:id="btnSum" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addSum" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="+" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
<Button fx:id="btnPoint" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addPoint" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="." GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
<Button fx:id="btnDivide" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="108.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addDivide" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="/" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
<Button fx:id="btn6" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="144.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="6" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
<Button fx:id="btnMultiply" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="144.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addMultiply" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="*" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
<Button fx:id="btnSub" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="185.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addSubtract" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
</children>
```

Тут мы убрали лисенеры на `onClick` для всех цифровых кнопок.

Теперь, перейдем к созданию евента и установкой на все кнопки

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    MyEvent btnEvent = new MyEvent();
    btn0.setOnAction(btnEvent);
    btn1.setOnAction(btnEvent);
    btn2.setOnAction(btnEvent);
    btn3.setOnAction(btnEvent);
    btn4.setOnAction(btnEvent);
    btn5.setOnAction(btnEvent);
    btn6.setOnAction(btnEvent);
    btn7.setOnAction(btnEvent);
    btn8.setOnAction(btnEvent);
    btn9.setOnAction(btnEvent);
}
```

**P.S.**

```
switch (btn.getText()) {
     case "0":
         System.out.println("0");
         break;
     case "1":
         System.out.println("1");
         break;
     case "2":
         System.out.println("2");
         break;
     case "3":
         System.out.println("3");
         break;
     case "4":
         System.out.println("4");
         break;
     сase "5":
         System.out.println("5");
         break;
     case "6":
         System.out.println("6");
         break;
     case "7":
         System.out.println("7");
         break;
     сase "8":
         System.out.println("8");
         break;
     case "9":
         System.out.println("9");
         break;
     }
 }
```

замена на

```
System.out.println(btn.getText());
```

Comment: Спасибо, Андрей.